# How to delete all postgresql data from docker including created users and databses?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I used to create postgresql database for my old project with command:

```
docker run --name oldpostgresqldb -e POSTGRES_USER=oldadmin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -p 5432:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

Then create database with command:

```
docker exec -i oldpostgresqldb psql -U oldadmin -c "CREATE DATABASE oldDB WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=oldadmin;"
```

When I started my new project stoped and removed all containers, images, volumes etc. and even used `docker system prune`.

Now I am trying to create new container and db with commands:

```
docker run --name newpostgresqldb -e POSTGRES_USER=newadmin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -p 5432:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

and

```
docker exec -i newpostgresqldb psql -U newadmin -c "CREATE DATABASE newDB WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=newadmin;"
```

But I receive `psql: error: FATAL:  role "newadmin" does not exist`.
Furthermore, I still can manage `oldDB` with `oldadmin` user in `newpostgresqldb` container, because user `oldadmin` is still exists.

How can I delete old data and create new user and database using docker?

Comment: did you delete the content of `/data` in the host?

Comment: @Ay0 not sure, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Ay0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4093955/ay0) I've found a solution. I just needed to clear content of `/data` folder in the host directory manualy.